# Fatal Error when saving a product in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.8

When I try and edit a sku in our inventory.  I'm now getting this error message.  Not sure if it is a DB issue now.  We also are having a problem with our coupon codes not work either. [Link to old problem](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Updated-SUPEE-6788-now-newly-created-promotion-codes-are-not/m-p/21314#U21314)

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
>   on line 587 Warning: include(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
>   Warning: include(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line
>   93 Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
>   on line 244 Warning: include(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
>   Warning: include(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line
>   93 Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in
>   /chroot/home/store/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php
>   on line 108

```css
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /chroot/home/sports/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 587 Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'SEESION_MAX_COOKIE_LIFETIME' in /chroot/home/sports/SPORTS.COM/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php on line 120
```

Comment: There is most likely an issue with an extension you're using. Have you added any recently?

Comment: I have not added anything recently other than upgrading most of them to be compatible with the latest SUPEE Patch.  That is when I noticed these issues.   What's the best way to troubleshoot the extensions?  Disable them one at a time till it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, yeah, you'll have to disable them and check for this error. Also unfortunately, the admin disable option only disables output- not the actual extension. The best method here would be to remove the module declaration from the /etc/modules/ folder, rebuild the cache, check the site, replace the declaration and remove the next one, rinse and repeat. :\ EDIT: PS, consider voting on comments! ;)

Comment: This is the most absolutely random thing ever.  1 in 10 tries works.  I disabled every extension I have and it still give me a that error sometimes. Ever since the Supee patch ive started to have random issues.

Comment: I have isolated the  save product issue to M2EPro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All started with the most recent patch.

The real problem lies within the multi-store setup I had previously had.   Initially I had 3 stores in one instance and we reverted it back to 1 store and removed the stores from the store view.  I added back a store view so that I have 2 now and it solved the problem above.